# Bootstrap carousel prev button not working in mobile version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used bootstrap carousel its working properly in desktop version, but in mobile version when we click prev button next button is working please anyone help me. Herewith am sharing code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQLAt.png)

Please check the link sir
URL: http://www.josephgroup.ae/fascia-signs.php

```
enter code here

 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <!-- <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li> -->
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="6"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="7"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="8"></li>
            <!-- <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="9"></li> -->
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="9"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="10"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="11"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="12"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="13"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="14"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="15"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="16"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="17"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="18"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="19"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="20"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="21"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="22"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="23"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="24"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="25"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="26"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="27"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="28"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="29"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="30"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="31"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="32"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="33"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="34"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="35"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="36"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="37"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="38"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="39"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="40"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="41"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="42"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="43"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="44"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="45"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="46"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="47"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="48"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="49"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="50"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="51"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="52"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="53"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="54"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="55"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="56"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="57"></li>
          </ol><!-- indicator -->
          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
               <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/2.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/3.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/4.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/5.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div> -->
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/6.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/7.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/8.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/9.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/10.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/11.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div> -->
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/12.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/13.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/14.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/15.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/16.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/17.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/1a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/2a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/3a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/4a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/5a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/6a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/7a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/8a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/9a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/10a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/11a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/12a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/13a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/14a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/15a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/16a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/17a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/18a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/19a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/20a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/21a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/22a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/23a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/24a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/25a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/26a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/27a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/28a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/29a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/30a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/31a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/32a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/33a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/34a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/35a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/36a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/37a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/38a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/39a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/40a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/41a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/42a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="images/product/detail/signage/fascia-signs/43a.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Revolutionize your business</p>
              </div>
            </div>                            
          </div>
          <!-- Left and right controls -->
          <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" role="button" onclick="$('#myCarousel').carousel('prev')">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"  aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" role="button" onclick="$('#myCarousel').carousel('next')">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"  aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>              
        </div><!--mycarousel  -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKgK1.png)

Heading

Comment: put some code and screenshot

Comment: Please anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for above problem **carousel-control right** class width overriding **carousel-control left** class thats why  prev button not working.